# Stop copying file in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, copy, fsevents

I'm facing a problem I using the `FSEvent` to catch the file created in my app but I also want to check the file extension (ex: photo/ video type) are allowed, otherwise these files will not be copied. How can I check the file extension before copying in Cocoa? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

**Please note I don't use `NSFileManager` to copy file.**

Comment: what do you use to copy? usually when fsevent comes in, it might be too late.

Comment: The copy is performed by OS, I mean I mounted a virtual drive , copy file to that virtual drive but i want to check the extension of these file before copying. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible to check the type using NSURL and NSURLTypeIdentifierKey

Comment: Thanks, can you show sample code? after checking the type of file, can we stop copying file ?

Comment: Sure, sample code in answer

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to check for movies or audio file types. [Full list of UTI-Types in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html).

```
  NSString * fileUTI = nil;
  BOOL success = [self getResourceValue:& fileUTI forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey];
  if (success && [uti isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    BOOL fileConformsToUTI = UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie);
    fileConformsToUTI = fileConformsToUTI || UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeAudio);
    // check and do the copy
  }
```

Comment: @NTNT  did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it?